# Android send file in the cache with file provider

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I want to open a file with an intent. My file is in cache. I get my file's Uri in fileUri. I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
android.content.res.XmlResourceParser 
android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData
(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String) on a null object reference
```

I have defined a fileprovider in my manifest file as this:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.app.firm.app"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

I also have a xml file in res/xml folder called file_paths.xml
In file_paths xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<cache-path name="my_cache" path="." />
</paths>
```

Opening file with Uri. Error comes from

```
uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity._inst, "com.app.firm.app", file);


public void openfile(Uri fileUri)
{
    String mimeType = getMimeType(fileUri);

    String fileUriStr = fileUri.getLastPathSegment();

    Uri uri=null;
    File file = new File(MainActivity._inst.getCacheDir(), fileUriStr);
    if(file.exists())
    {uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity._inst, "com.app.firm.app", file);}

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, mimeType);

    MainActivity._inst.startActivity(intent);

}


public String getMimeType(Uri uri) {
    String mimeType = null;
    if (uri.getScheme().equals(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT)) {
        ContentResolver cr = MainActivity._inst.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
        mimeType = cr.getType(uri);
    } else {
        String fileExtension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(uri.toString());
        mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(
                fileExtension.toLowerCase());
    }
    return mimeType;
}
```

Please help me!!

Comment: `MainActivity._inst` ? Please showtype and the value.

Comment: any type of file. But for now I am trying pdf.But let me say this normally I open an encrypted pdf file and while decrypting I write it to the cache directory. Then I get its path and want to open the pdf file with some application. Cache directory I write to is : /data/data/com.app.firm.app/cache/test.pdf.

Comment: Is `_inst` a file? Well no. Please put it in your code so we can see what it is.

Comment: it is this 'public static Context _inst;'

Comment: `public void openfile(Uri fileUri)` is a member of which class?

Comment: It is a member of Asynctask class. I call after progress ends